# How can I use *ngFor current object outside of the ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

The title might seem weird but what im talking about is basically what [this link](http://johnculviner.com/expandable-collapsable-detail-in-a-table-with-angular-js/) is doing.

Im look for a way to use the current iterated `person` in a `<tr>` outside of the `*ngFor` scope.

In the link he used `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to include multiple tag withing the `ng-repeat.` How can i achieve the same behavior withing Angular2 using `*ngFor`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to use the `<template>` tag, which made the iterated objected accessible within it.

```
<ng-template let-person ngFor [ngForOf]="people">
    <tr>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
    </tr>
    <div>
        <span>{{person.details}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Hope it'll help somebody

Comment: Could you provide a link to Angular documentation on why this works?  The information I got on the use of the HTML 5 template tag: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template

Answer (score 0):

The * in *ngFor (and really any angular directive) is shorthand that tells angular to surround the element in an ng-template, which is just the angular implementation of . You can read about how that happens at https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives, but I'll reproduce the relevant example below.

If your code contains

`<div *ngIf='object'>{{object.property}}</div>`

as part of the render process, angular transposes that to

```
<ng-template [ngIf]='object'>
   <div>{{object.property}}</div>
</ng-template>
```